# Having trouble changing gxt label widget style in UI Binder xml file

Tags: css, gwt, gxt

Basically I want to change the style of the gxt widget FieldLabel element Label which is generated element by GXT.

It has the style class: 
`com-sencha-gxt-theme-base-client-field-FieldLabelDefaultAppearance-Style-fieldElement`

and the actual style according firebug is set in:

```
element.style {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The problem is that I can't override that width of 100px;

I have the form like this:

```
<container:FlowLayoutContainer>
         <form:FieldSet ui:field="fieldSet" headingText="User Information" collapsible="true" height="70" >
            <container:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
              <container:child layoutData="{horizontalLayoutData}">
                <form:FieldLabel text="From" >
                  <form:widget>
                    <form:TextField allowBlank="false" />
                  </form:widget>
                </form:FieldLabel>
              </container:child>
              <container:child layoutData="{horizontalLayoutData}">
                <form:FieldLabel text="To">
                  <form:widget>
                    <form:TextField allowBlank="false" />
                  </form:widget>
                </form:FieldLabel>
              </container:child>
            </container:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
          </form:FieldSet>
        </container:FlowLayoutContainer>
```

Any solutions for the problem?

I tried many ways but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!important` to override label's width via CSS.

But I recommend you to change width by sencha's method [setLabelWidth(int)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/FieldLabel.html#setLabelWidth(int)) via Java code

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the answer for doing it:

```
<form:FieldLabel text="From" labelWidth="40" >
```